# How to use scheduler on a specific part of Python code?

Tags: python

I have to run a code which updates the details about 5 tables(table name, date, number of observations in the table on that date). The number of entries for these tables(A,B,C,D,E) are updated on a daily basis. The agenda is to create  a history table which holds records date wise for all the tables. I made the code and need to apply the scheduler so that the code runs every 24 hrs. The problem is that I want to put only certain part of my code in scheduler and not the complete code. How do I do it ?

```
## History table which will only run at the start of the process
data = [('A',len(A),t),('B',len(B),t),('C',len(C),t),('D',len(D),t),('E',len(E),t)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','LENGTH','date'])
df

## This code will run everyday and will merge with the history table

import sched
import time

scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)


def auto_table():


    import datetime
    t= datetime.date.today()-datetime.timedelta(days=0)
    t

    data = [['A',len(A),t],['B',len(B),t],['C',len(C),t],['D',len(D),t],   ['E',len(E),t]]
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','LENGTH','date'])
    global df
    df=df.merge(df1,how='outer')

    return df



print ('START:', time.time())
scheduler.enter(1, 1, auto_table())

scheduler.run()
```

I got this error:

```
START: 1547819432.8968043

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-199-f7820889e2d5> in <module>()
     22 scheduler.enter(1, 1, auto_table())
     23 
---> 24 scheduler.run()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\sched.py in run(self, blocking)
    152                 delayfunc(time - now)
    153             else:
--> 154                 action(*argument, **kwargs)
    155                 delayfunc(0)   # Let other threads run
    156 

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

Comment: Please put code/output/large in code blocks. The editor has a button for it.

Comment: I am using Jupyter Notebooks. What shall I add in that ?

Comment: I meant in this question. Looks like deceze correct your issue with how the question was written. All should be good :)

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/kl09/py_scheduler
Python Scheduler, check Read.me for example